# Extend the "core/link" Block Format

Tags: block-editor

StackExchange Community,

I am currently using `editor.BlockEdit` block filter to extend the core blocks. I need a way of extending `core/link` format on multiple blocks (image, button, paragraph, possibly others) but have yet to find a way to extend the actual format. What we need is a way to add attributes to the `core/link` format that will allow us to add data attributes to the `<a>` tag. For example:

```
<a href="/my-link/" data-post-id="433" data-post-type="custom-post-type">
```

I am aware that there is a way to register custom formats using `registerFormatType` on rich-text based blocks or adding the `ToolbarGroup` & `ToolbarButton` component to the other block types but my this approach caused conflicts involving errors and multiple a tags. Any help or thoughts on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not yet possible using the core/link as of this answer; visit https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/16929 and https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/23011